# How to resolve content is empty error in NLU Watson API?

Tags: python, watson-nlu

I am streaming tweets in a file `tweet.txt` and using another python script, I am reading the tweets and sending them to Watson. Sometimes, there generates an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "readingTweets.py", line 44,
>   in 
>       language='en'   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_understanding_v1.py",
>   line 173, in analyze
>       method='POST', url=url, params=params, json=data, accept_json=True)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_service.py",
>   line 385, in request
>       info=error_info, httpResponse=response) watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error:
>   invalid request: content is empty, Code: 400 , X-dp-watson-tran-id:
>   gateway02-582988317 , X-global-transaction-id:
>   ffea405d5adda40d22bfb21d

My code sample is:

```
while 1:
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        if (line):
            print "-----------------------------"
            print "the line is: "
            print line
            print "-----------------------------"
            response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
                text=line,
                features=Features(
                    entities=EntitiesOptions(
                        emotion=True,
                        sentiment=True,
                        limit=2),
                    keywords=KeywordsOptions(
                        emotion=True,
                        sentiment=True,
                        limit=2)),
                language='en'
                )
            print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Comment: It is what it is `Error: invalid request: content is empty` no content. You probably try to parse it or do some action with it but there's nothing and crash... We can't actually run your code, it would be helpful if you could provide a working prototype.

Comment: Got it! There were some backslash-n (\n) lines and I put a check only on empty ones. Hence, no content was provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is what it is `Error: invalid request: content is empty no content` or invalid characters. 
You suggested that there were chars like `\n` used and you checked only for the empty ones.